# Conjugate of an algebraic number

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $P$ be an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb Q[X]$ with degree $n\ge1$. Denote by $\alpha$ a root of $P$. Does it exist a polynomial $Q$ of $\mathbb Q[X]$ with degree $\ge2$ such that $Q(\alpha)$ is a root of $P$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure.   Let $Q(x)=P(x)+x$.  (at least if degree $P(x)≥2$, though you could always take $Q(x)=xP(x)+x$ if you felt like it).

Comment: Indeed, let $Q(x) = R(x)P(x)+x$ for any polynomial $R$. In general that's the best we can do—consider $P(X)=X^3-2$ and $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$.